Interactive Brokers OAuth1 live_session_token
Given the general community consensus that IB's OAuth just doesn't work I'm not expecting an answer but it would be much appreciated
I've been following this
https://www.interactivebrokers.com/campus/ibkr-api-page/cpapi-v1/#lst
I wasted a day trying to get the C# code working, gave up and thought I'd have a go at the python code found here
Other than the lack of references and some ?typos, I still get a 401
Has anyone got this to work or can see anything I'm doing obviously wrong
MacOS, M2, Python3
import random
import base64
from datetime import datetime
import requests
from urllib.parse import quote_plus, quote
from Crypto.Signature import pkcs1_15 as PKCS1_v1_5_Signature
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

# Generate a random 256-bit integer.
dh_random = random.getrandbits(256)

access_token_secret = 'see_image'
consumer_key = 'see_image'
access_token = 'see_image'
baseUrl = 'api.ibkr.com/v1/api/'
realm = 'limited_poa'

with open("./dhparam_aum_ib.pem", "r") as f:
    dh_param = RSA.importKey(f.read())
    dh_prime = dh_param.n # Also known as DH Modulus
    dh_generator = dh_param.e  # always =2
# Convert result to hex and remove leading 0x chars.
dh_challenge = hex(pow(base=dh_generator, exp=dh_random, mod=dh_prime))[2:]


# Compute the Diffie-Hellman challenge:
# generator ^ dh_random % dh_prime
# Note that IB always uses generator = 2.
# Convert result to hex and remove leading 0x chars.

with open("./private_encryption.pem", "r") as f:
    encryption_key = RSA.importKey(f.read())
bytes_decrypted_secret = PKCS1_v1_5.new(
    key=encryption_key
    ).decrypt(
        ciphertext=base64.b64decode(access_token_secret),
        sentinel=None,
        )
prepend = bytes_decrypted_secret.hex()

base_string = prepend
# Elements of the LST request so far.
method = 'POST'
url = f'https://{baseUrl}/oauth/live_session_token'
oauth_params = {
    "oauth_consumer_key": consumer_key,
    "oauth_nonce": hex(random.getrandbits(128))[2:],
    "oauth_timestamp": str(int(datetime.now().timestamp())),
    "oauth_token": access_token,
    "oauth_signature_method": "RSA-SHA256",
    "diffie_hellman_challenge": dh_challenge,
}
# Combined param key=value pairs must be sorted alphabetically by key
# and ampersand-separated.
params_string = "&".join([f"{k}={v}" for k, v in sorted(oauth_params.items())])
# Base string = method + url + sorted params string, all URL-encoded.
base_string += f"{method}&{quote_plus(url)}&{quote(params_string)}"
# Convert base string str to bytestring.
encoded_base_string = base_string.encode("utf-8")
# Generate SHA256 hash of base string bytestring.
sha256_hash = SHA256.new(data=encoded_base_string)
# Generate bytestring PKCS1v1.5 signature of base string hash.
# RSA signing key is private signature key.
bytes_pkcs115_signature = PKCS1_v1_5_Signature.new(
    rsa_key=encryption_key
    ).sign(msg_hash=sha256_hash)
# Generate str from base64-encoded bytestring signature.
b64_str_pkcs115_signature = base64.b64encode(bytes_pkcs115_signature).decode("utf-8")
# URL-encode the base64 signature str and add to oauth params dict.
oauth_params['oauth_signature'] = quote_plus(b64_str_pkcs115_signature)
# Oauth realm param omitted from signature, added to header afterward.
oauth_params["realm"] = realm
# Assemble oauth params into auth header value as comma-separated str.
oauth_header = "OAuth " + ", ".join([f'{k}="{v}"' for k, v in sorted(oauth_params.items())])
# Create dict for LST request headers including OAuth Authorization header.
headers = {"Authorization": oauth_header}
# Add User-Agent header, required for all requests. Can have any value.
headers["User-Agent"] = "python/3.11"
# Prepare and send request to /live_session_token, print request and response.
lst_request = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers)
# Check if request returned 200, proceed to compute LST if true, exit if false.
if not lst_request.ok:
    print(f"ERROR: Request to /live_session_token failed. Exiting...")
    raise SystemExit(0)
# Script not exited, proceed to compute LST.
response_data = lst_request.json()
dh_response = response_data["diffie_hellman_response"]
lst_signature = response_data["live_session_token_signature"]
lst_expiration = response_data["live_session_token_expiration"]



The code on the IB website, both the C# and Python
Also tried the TESTCONS and test_realm, but its not apparent where to get a token and token secret

For anyone wanting to fully automate the login and use the REST API with interactive brokers, theres a functioning python project here
https://github.com/sharkeyboy/ib_python
This is IB's code, not mine
